# Por que navigation properties precisam ser declaradas como virtual?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou mapeando um relacionamento **1 x N** utilizando uma classe **POCO** (*Plain Old CLR Object*) para ser utilizada com o *Entity Framework 6*. Neste caso, possuo uma entidade **Carrinho** que possui vários **Produtos**:

```
public class Carrinho
{
    //Outras propriedades da classe

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }  
}

public class Produto
{
    //Propriedades da classe
}
```

Neste cenário, dizemos que a propriedade **Produtos** da classe **Carrinho** é uma *navigation property*. Por que ela deve ser marcada como `virtual`?

Comment: Eu nem me liguei que já tinha essa pergunta no site.

Comment: Eu também não, realmente está duplicada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece que criando a propriedade como `virtual` o Entity Framework vai criar uma nova classe (o que é chamado de *dynamic proxy*) em tempo de execução e usá-la ao invés de usar a classe original.

Esta nova classe, que foi criada dinamicamente, contém o código (a lógica) necessária para carregar as entidades do banco de dados no primeiro acesso à propriedade. Dessa forma, o EF não precisa carregar toda a árvore de objetos relacionado quando for buscar algum registro. Isso é o que se chama de Lazy Loading.